# How to make sure Ubuntu update is done and finished?

Tags: ubuntu

I recently was updating Ubuntu on my home server. Something went wrong and I needed to reboot the machine. It looks like after that everything was updated and everything works. It looks like new Ubuntu 10.10. But when I ssh to this system, I can see the welcome message saying "Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS". So something went wrong :(

Update-manager says all the packages are updated, also when started with `-dc` options (distribution upgrade). What can I do now? How to get rid of this wrong message and have good one?

Despite I use this machine as a server, the system there is Ubuntu Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your /etc/apt/sources.list and swap out 'maverick' for your 'lucid' entries, then from the terminal run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.